# How to set a permanent IP address on "Snappy" Ubuntu Core

Tags: ubuntu-core

I'm trying to use "Snappy" Ubuntu Core on a virtual environment (virt-manager) but I didn't see any guide to explain how to set a permanent IP address on Snappy. If I run this command:

**`$: kvm -m 512 -redir :8090::80 -redir :8022::22 ubuntu-core-alpha-02_amd64-virt.img`**

Qemu gets an IP address to Snappy. I saw there is this file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0, and inside that there are these lines:

```
$: more /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I also try to edit that via Vi as sudo but receive this error

```
W10 Warning: Changing a readonly file
```

someone knows how to edit that and to set a static IP address?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug report here on that particular issue.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy-ubuntu/+bug/1405795/+activity

Comment: OP has mentioned that he/she has used `sudo` already..

Comment: my bad, didn't see that one. Interesting.. it seems like this puppy has some kind of unionfs mount all over the place. I'll update when I find something. Nice puzzle.

Comment: seems like / is mounted as ro. 
   sudo mount / -o rw,remount 
it will make your /etc writable and allow you to sudo edit the interface. Not sure this is the intended way of customizing tho.

Comment: changing things in /etc after remount is not persistent after reboots.

Comment: I can't believe we've to make that to assign a static IP address to Snappy. It seems to be the only way

Comment: Well, it's too early for the project. I mean if you try their snappy command to build jails, it crashes for many of the parameters. Give it more time to grow, or join the effort and be a comrade on the battlefront. Either ways, I expect things will change in time.

Comment: any news for this bug?